# date_query in pre_get_posts out of memory

Tags: wp-query, pre-get-posts, fatal-error, date-query

I'm trying to apply a Datefilter for specific categories.

Wordpress crashs with a out of memory error. Is this a server problem or is my query wrong?
At first I tried query -> (...) but with approach I get an error, cause of too few arguments.
While using query = new WP_Query... I get the out of memory error.

Thank you for your help.

My code:

```
    function test_filter( $query ) {
        $options = get_option('dh_options');
        $cats = "54,55,56";
        if ($options['checkbox_usr_q'] == true) {
            if ( !is_admin()  && $query->is_main_query() && $query->in_category($cats)) {
                $args = array(
                    'date_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
                            'after' => 'May 1st, 2021',
                            'inclusive' => true
                        ),
                    ),
                    'posts_per_page' => -1
                );
                $query = new WP_Query( $args );
            }
        }
    }

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'test_filter' , 100, 3);
```

Error Message:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 699400192) (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /homepages/1/d861373325/htdocs/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 892

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 699400192) (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /homepages/1/d861373325/htdocs/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-recovery-mode.php on line 361
```

Comment: While it won't fix your issue (see Jacobs answer), `'posts_per_page' => -1` is not recommended, you should set an upper limit, even if it's a limit you never expect to reach, e.g 500 to ensure that you never try to load more posts than your server is capable of loading, if only for performance reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `pre_get_posts` correctly. You've called `new WP_Query` which then runs your hook, which calls `new WP_Query`, which then runs your hook... and so on. You're in an infinite loop.

The proper way to use `pre_get_posts` is to modify the `$query` parameter using `$query->set()` to adjust the query. You don't need to perform a brand new query:

```
function test_filter( $query ) {
    $options = get_option( 'dh_options' );
    $cats    = array( 54, 55, 56 );

    if ( $options['checkbox_usr_q'] == true ) {
        if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_category( $cats ) ) {
            $query->set(
                'date_query',
                array(
                    array(
                        'column'    => 'post_date_gmt',
                        'after'     => 'May 1st, 2021',
                        'inclusive' => true,
                    ),
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that I changed `$query->in_category`, which doesn't exist, to `$query->is_category`, and I changed the value to an array of IDs. That function does not accept a comma-separated string.

Comment: Thank you for the fix and explanation, you're awesome! Now it works!